# Overflow error when calling ERC20 method 'transferFrom' from web3

Tags: erc-20, transferfrom, overflow

I'm just trying to transfer from one of my smart contracts in Ropsten to my wallet 1.02 WETH with this line

```
const deposit = weth.methods.transferFrom(contract,wallet,1020000000000000000).send({from:wallet}).then(console.log)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from",
> value=1020000000000000000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT,
> version=bignumber/5.3.0)

The amount has a precision of 18 decimals, and if I'm not mistaken that should be correct, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that javascript numbers do not have enough precision.

Use [`web3.utils.toBN`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-utils.html#tobn) to wrap them in a BigNumber object

```
const amount = web3.utils.toBN("1020000000000000000")
const deposit = weth.methods.transferFrom(contract,wallet,amount).send({from:wallet}).then(console.log)
```

Since they are ether amounts perhaps it is better to use [`web3.utils.toWei`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-utils.html#towei)

```
const amount = web3.utils.toWei("1.02", "ether")
```